# 2D Array, best average calculator using HashMap

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, space-complexity

**Problem Statement:** I have a 2D array of strings containing student names and respective marks as below

```
String[][] scores = {{"Bob","85"},{"Mark","100"},{"Charles","63"},{"Mark","34"}};
```

I want to calculate the best average among all the students available, i.e with the above input the best average should be 85.

**My Attempt:**
I tried to solve this using HashMap as below.

```
public int  bestAverageCalculator(String[][] scores) {

    // This HashMap maps student name to their list of scores
    Map<String,List<Integer>> scoreMap = new HashMap<String,List<Integer>>();
    for(String[] score:scores) {
        String name = score[0];
        int currentScore =Integer.parseInt(score[1]);

        if(scoreMap.containsKey(name)) {
            List<Integer> scoreList = scoreMap.get(name);
            scoreList.add(currentScore);
            scoreMap.put(name, scoreList);
        }
        else {
            List<Integer> scoreList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            scoreList.add(currentScore);
            scoreMap.put(name, scoreList);
        }
    }
    //scoreMap will be {Charles=[63], Bob=[85], Mark=[100, 34]}
    //After Map is formed i am iterating though all the values and finding the best average as below
    int bestAverage = 0;
    for(List<Integer> value:scoreMap.values()) {
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for(int i:value) {
            sum+=i;
            count++;
        }
        int average = (int)Math.floor(sum/count);
        if(average>bestAverage)
            bestAverage = average;
    }

    return bestAverage;// returns 85

}
```

The implementation is correct and i am getting the answer as expected, but i was told the space complexity of the program is more and it can be achieved without using the `List<Integer>` for marks, i am not able to understand how average can be calculated on fly without storing list of marks.

Please suggest if any other methods can solve this other than HashMap.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store for each student a constant amount of data :

1. the student's name
2. the sum of all the student's marks
3. the number of the student's marks

This will make the space complexity `O(m)` where `m` is the number of unique students (instead of your `O(n)` where `n` is the number of marks).

For example, you can have a `Student` class with these 3 properties (and store the data in a `List<Student>`), or you can have a `Map<String,int[]>` with the key being the student's name and the value being an array of two elements containing the sum of the marks and the number of marks.

You can construct this data while iterating over the input.

Now you can compute the average for each student and find the highest average.

Comment: You mean to say Arrays are better compared to ArrayList when it comes to space complexity?

Comment: @raviraja no, using an ArrayList instead of array would still have the same asymptotic space complexity. The point is that the array or ArrayList will have a constant (2) number of elements.

Comment: Ok, understood, instead of storing all the marks i have to store the sum and count values in a array of space 2. Thank you very much, accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well for space saving you can store two numbers per person
`avgSum` and `count` and calculate average on the end.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented @Eran 's approach based on your code with a `Map<String,int[]>` with

key: student's name

value: an array of two elements `[the sum of the scores, the number of scores]`

```
public int  bestAverageCalculator(String[][] scores) {

    // This HashMap maps student name to their total scores and count in an int array format of [totalScores, count]
    Map<String,int[]> scoreMap = new HashMap<String,int[]>();
    for(String[] score:scores) {
        String name = score[0];
        int currentScore =Integer.parseInt(score[1]);

        if(scoreMap.containsKey(name)) {
            int[] scoreCount = scoreMap.get(name);
            scoreCount[0] += currentScore;
            scoreCount[1] ++;
            scoreMap.put(name, scoreCount);
        }
        else {
            int[] scoreCount = new int[]{currentScore, 1};
            scoreMap.put(name, scoreCount);
        }
    }

    int bestAverage = 0;
    for(int[] value:scoreMap.values()) {
        int average = (int)Math.floor(value[0]/value[1]);
        if(average>bestAverage)
            bestAverage = average;
    }

    return bestAverage;// returns 85

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Eran's idea but with `Student` class, at least for me it's much more clear

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    static String[][] scores = {{"Bob", "85"}, {"Mark", "100"}, {"Charles", "63"}, {"Mark", "34"}};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String[] score : scores) {
            String name = score[0];
            int currentScore = Integer.parseInt(score[1]);

            Student student = findStudentByName(name, students);
            if (student != null) {
                student.setNumberOfScores(student.getNumberOfScores() + 1);
                student.setSumOfScores(student.getSumOfScores() + currentScore);
            } else {
                student = new Student(name, 1, currentScore);
                students.add(student);
            }
        }
        findStudentWithBestAverage(students);
    }

    private static void findStudentWithBestAverage(List<Student> students) {
        Student bestStudent = null;
        int bestAverage = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
            if ((students.get(i).getSumOfScores() / students.get(i).getNumberOfScores()) > bestAverage) {
                bestStudent = students.get(i);
                bestAverage = (students.get(i).getSumOfScores() / students.get(i).getNumberOfScores());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(bestStudent + " with average: " + bestAverage);
    }

    private static Student findStudentByName(String name, List<Student> students) {
        for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
            if (students.get(i).getName().equals(name)) {
                return students.get(i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static class Student {
        private String name;
        private int numberOfScores;
        private int sumOfScores;

        public Student(String name, int numberOfScores, int sumOfScores) {
            this.name = name;
            this.numberOfScores = numberOfScores;
            this.sumOfScores = sumOfScores;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getNumberOfScores() {
            return numberOfScores;
        }

        public void setNumberOfScores(int numberOfScores) {
            this.numberOfScores = numberOfScores;
        }

        public int getSumOfScores() {
            return sumOfScores;
        }

        public void setSumOfScores(int sumOfScores) {
            this.sumOfScores = sumOfScores;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Student student = (Student) o;
            return name.equals(student.name);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(name);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Student{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", numberOfScores=" + numberOfScores +
                    ", sumOfScores=" + sumOfScores +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```